# No code gets executed after loop with promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

So I have a function which takes an id and returns the corresponding property map via a promise. So I made a loop and iterate my function with all my Ids but it never executes the code outside of the loop.

```
async getProps(dbId) {
    const properties = Viewer.properties //creates an empty map
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.gui.getProperties(
                    dbId,
                    args => {
                        console.log('properties', args)
                        resolve(args.properties)
                    },
                    reject
                )
            })

            prom.then(props => {
                properties.set(dbId, props)
                resolve(properties.entries())
            })
            console.log('properties', properties)
        }
    )
}
```

What I want is to create a map with the ID as key and the array of properties as value. This happens as intended.

This is how I use the function

```
async getConcreteIds() {
    let wallfloorids = this.getWallIds().concat(this.getFloorIds());
    // let concreteIds = [];
    for(let id of wallfloorids) {
        let p1 = await this.view.getProps(id);
        console.log(p1);
    }
    console.log("Hello");
}
```

I iterate through my IDs and call the `getProperties` function and it logs the map as intended. But it never leaves the loop. `wallfloorids` has 52 entries, so it is not an endless loop.
I think the structure of my getProperties function is the cause, but I do not know what to change. I tried changing the structure, but then it returns an empty map and the rest of the code is executed.
Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `this.view.getProperties` in `getConcreteIds`. Where is it defined ? Is there some confusion with `getProps` ?

Comment: My bad I changed the name while typing the question. Sloppy from my side. Editing it right now

Comment: Don't make getProps `async` if it explicitly returns a promise. And why are you wrapping promises in promises in getProps ?

Comment: I think it was a working remnant of a try and error process. I implemented the changes and         
`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.gui.getProperties(
                dbId,
                args => {
                    console.log('properties', args)
                    resolve(args.properties)
                },
                reject
            )
        }) `
I basically unwrapped it and returned the single promise. It is still able to return the property, but it does not execute the code after the loop

Comment: It was fixed by implementing your changes and removing the await and instead using p1.then(props=>{}). Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you write an answer with the correct code and then accept it.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now State

```
getProperties(dbId) {
    const properties = Viewer.properties
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.gui.getProperties(
            dbId,
            args => {
                resolve(args.properties)
            },
            reject
        )
    })

}


async getConcreteIds() {
    let wallfloorids = this.getWallIds().concat(this.getFloorIds());
    let concreteIds = [];
    for (let id of wallfloorids) {
        let p1 = await this.view.getProperties(id);
        console.log(p1);
            for (let prop of p1){
                if (prop.displayCategory === "Materialien und Oberflächen" && prop.displayValue.contains("Concrete"))
                    concreteIds.push(id);
            }
    }
    return concreteIds;
}

onlyConcrete() {
    let ids = [];
    const concreteIds = this.getConcreteIds();
    console.log(concreteIds);
    this.viewer.isolateById(concreteIds)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `p1.then` when you can `await p1`

Comment: I tried replacing my p1.then with await right now and it results in a forever pending Promise and my program becomes unresponsive. I will update my code above. The `p1.then` approach delivered a result, but the `this.viewer.isolateById(concreteIds)` does not wait for concreteIds to have values, which is another problem